# How to use ListView in Hub Section?

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I am adding a ListView in one of my Hub Section 
But I can't see any static data while running the app.

```XAML
<Hub x:Name="Hub" x:Uid="Hub" 
         Header="Vantage Circle"  
         Foreground="Purple" Background="White">
        <HubSection  x:Name="HubSection1"
                      Header="Exclusive Deals">
            <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView
                         IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                         ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,27.5">
                                    <TextBlock Width="300" FontSize="22" Text="Hello"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>      
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

Can you please guide me in right direction and/or provide me sample examples of using a listView inside a hub template. Thanks

Comment: What static data you are asking for..? You are using datatemplate... Where you are setting itemsource to Listbox. Post your C# code.

Comment: Static means Hello in the TextBlock
At first trying to make the ListView Then I will go for Binding and other stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then Remove ItemTemplate from XAML code Like this

```
<Hub x:Name="Hub" x:Uid="Hub" 
             Header="Vantage Circle"  
             Foreground="Purple" Background="White">
            <HubSection  x:Name="HubSection1"
                          Header="Exclusive Deals">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView
                             IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                             ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">

                                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,27.5">
                                    <TextBlock Width="300" FontSize="22" Text="Hello"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>
        </Hub>
```

**Edit :**

Yes. It displays one item only. Bcz there is no itemtemplate. As I said before you have to use ItemSource to Display to bunch of data.

```
     I am adding a ListView in one of my Hub Section But I can't see any static
 data while running the app.
```

But your question states that you want to display Static Data. So I told you to remove Itemtemplate & here is the solution.

[This](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListViewSimple-d5fc27dd/sourcecode?fileId=44767&pathId=295881687) is a great sample for ListView & Binding. Help yourself to way to binding for Listview.

Hope this help, Let me know still if you face trouble...!

Comment: Item template will help in creating different Items in the listView, if I am not wrong but removing it will create only one item in the whole listView, I have tried the code you have suggested it is working but there is only one item. What I should I do to display list of items?